# Swift: how to implement additional view controllers with sprite kit game?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Ok, so I'm a beginner here and I am creating a game with Swift in sprite kit. 
So far in my storyboard I have the initial View Controller and the Game scene.

I know that my game scene is implemented via the `GameScene.swift` file, i.e whatever code I write in `GameScene.swift` affects and correlates to the Game scene.

This is all fine, However I do not understand where I can write code that alters the initial view controller.

I would have assumed that the view controller would be affected by code written in the `GameViewController.swift` file, however when I try to connect labels and image views from my storyboard to `GameViewController.swift` by pressing control and dragging, nothing connects. Thus, I have no way of implementing the initial view controller.

Similarly, I cannot implement any additional view controllers that I create in my storyboard.

I can put labels and image views and everything into my view controllers, but I can't connect them to any file to make them do anything.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have 2 different screens in the storyboard. Each view in a storyboard needs a separate view controller. To connect the ViewController.swift, you need to select the view in the storyboard, and in the identity inspector, make the class the viewController.